# Find highest number of consecutive outcomes for each person in list

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, spreadsheet

I've got an Excel list that looks like this (with the name in column A and the score in column B):

```
 N.  Nam  Score
 1.  Jim   7   
 2.  Jim   4   
 3.  Jim   4   
 4.  Jim   7
 5.  Jim   7
 6.  Jim   4
 7.  Jim   7
 8.  Jim   4
 9.  Ted   4
 10. Ted   4
 11. Ted   7
 12. Ted   7
 .
 .
 .
 n. cont'd
```

I need to rank each person by their highest number of **consecutive results of 7**.

Jim's max 7 result: 2; because he got a score of 7 twice in a row.

Ted's max 7 result 2; that's his maximum number.

How do I get Excel to tell me what the longest string of scores of 7 was for each person?

This is a sample of a long list.

Thanks!

Comment: Please let me know if it worked out for you and you can choose an answer that best fits for you or ask more questions.

Comment: Well Zero is MIA. Hey, no problem, glad I could help. Hello? As my words echo into the long dark empty room, dimly lit... LOL... "It's a long road..."

Answer (score 0):

I decided to give you an alternate solution and make it separate.

**Method 1**: Use a base case. We do this in math theory and proofs. Then use a case for all other entries/cells.

```
 - base case: 
   =IF(AND(A1=name,B2=num),1,0)
 - all other cases 
   =IF(AND(A2=A1,A2=name,B2=num),C1+1,IF(AND(A2=name,B2=num),1,0))
```

**Method 2**: Use an error proofing check and base case, all rolled into one long formula. It's much longer and can be pasted into each cell.

```
   =IF(NOT(ISERROR(OFFSET(H2,-1,0))),IF(AND(H2=OFFSET(H2,-1,0),H2=name,I2=num),OFFSET(J2,-1,0)+1,IF(AND(H2=name,I2=num),1,0)),1)
```

The setup: Use the setup you have, but add one column to the side of each Name/Score to make three columns instead of the two you have listed. This will be necessary to use a formula approach listed in methods 1 and 2.

As a bonus, I showed both methods on a few print-screens rolled into one solid image. An extra bonus, I demonstrate a drop-down-list to pick Names and Numbers (eg Jim's max at 7's, or Ted's max at 4's, or Keri's max at 5, to demonstrate a table and lists(tables for search-lists as numbered 1-to-5 in the image) for max results.


**Click On Image** : *to enlarge view*
[image]

Comment: Sorry about not responding. I didn't get a notification until I got the weekly email. Will remember to receive instant alerts next time.

Comment: Someone on another board eventually helped me (had gone unanswered for a while, so I posted here) using a VB script and I have no idea what it means. I was hoping to get an Excel solution so I could use it to teach myself other techniques in the future, so this is very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @ZeroCool Yeah I don't know why some people answer in VB cod. It should be ask for Apples, give apples. VB isn't necessary. It's just a nested IF(?, true do this, false do this) that does the trick combined with AND(?,?,?). Give it a try it's straight forward if you start from the left and logically walk your way through it. It if helped your question please check it on this page as answered. Take care!