# Excel Formula for Counting consecutive zeros

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data set that has intake values recorded for 100+ days on individual animals. I want to apply a formula to each animal ID and determine how many times the animal ate 0 for 2, 3, 4, etc days. I have applied the following formula but am not having any luck (DK3 is the number of consecutive zeros) .

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B5:DE5=0,COLUMN(B5:DE5)),IF(B5:DE5<>0,ROW(B5:DE5)))=DK3,1))`

How can I correct this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you please give us an example of your data and how it is laid out?

Comment: If you are still interested in the solution, I've improved it for your needs. For the animals :)

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question here for contiguous numbers and matching criteria:
[Find highest number of consecutive outcomes for each person in list](https://superuser.com/questions/1110593/find-highest-number-of-consecutive-outcomes-for-each-person-in-list/1110784#1110784)

**NOTE**: I hope the OP gets this. I did this for the name of Animals. If it's helping an animal let someone know how many days it hasn't eaten, then it's something you need to know. **♡♥ Animals! ♥♡**

For **contiguous numbers only** use this:

Put your first `0` in `A1`: then continue in `col(A)` your data scores down

Put this formula in `B1`: copy this formula adjacent to each score; `col(B)`

```
Let searchNumber=0,1,2,3,...n

=IF(  NOT(ISERROR(OFFSET(A1,-1,0))), IF(  AND(A1=OFFSET(A1,-1,0),A1=searchNumber),OFFSET(B1,-1,0)+1,IF(A1=searchNumber,1,0)  ),   IF(A1=searchNumber,1,0)  )

This is the count(ate?) formula for each cell in col(B)
```

To count the Maximum of the consequtive data (your case: 0), in an adjacent cell use this formuls: `=MAX(B:B)` will give you the HIGHEST amount of days '0'

Use other cells with this formula:

`=COUNTIF(B:B, 2)` this will give you how many times the animal ate ZERO two days in a row.

Here is what the data looks like: 

Let xx = Dog "Charlie"

Let ate=0,1 : 0=no, 1=yes

```
     col(A)       col(B)          
ID   ate?         formula:count(ate?)   count formula
---------------------------------------------------------
xx   0            1                     Max(b:b)=3
xx   0            2                     countif(b:b,2)=2
xx   1            0                     countif(b:b,2)=3
xx   1            0
xx   0            1
xx   0            2
xx   0            3
```

Charlie, ate ZERO, a max of 3-days in a row. Also he at ZERO two days in a row 2-times, and ZERO three days in a row 1-time.

Note:
`=OFFSET(ref, row, col)` row=`-1`=previous row, col=`-1`=col to left

So if your data looks like this:

```
  A               B     C    D    E        CW      CX (or another page)
1 ID              Day1  Day2 Day3 Day4 ... Day100
2 XX              1     0    0    1        1       
3 xx-count(ate?)  0     1    2    0        0       countif(b2:cw,2)=2
4 zz
5 zz-count(ate?)

Then the formula would look at column data instead of row data:
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(OFFSET(B2,-1,0))),IF(AND(B2=OFFSET(B2,0,-1),B2=searchNumber),OFFSET(B3,0,-1)+1,IF(B2=searchNumber,1,0)),IF(B2=searchNumber,1,0))

This formula would go into, starting at B3, then copying into C3,D3...
```

[image]

---

A better way to use the formula for multiple COUNTIF's and MAX: illustration
[image]